# Как добавить и реализовать Stepper на Navigation Bar от UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-development

День добрый, прохожу курсы на Swiftbook и сделал приложение на основе коллекций. Все очень просто и понятно, но возникли сложности при добавлении нового функционала. Все по порядку

Вот так выглядит мое приложение:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/68VpV.jpg

я пытаюсь сделать степпер чтоб он увеличивал количество ячеек в одной строке, для этого добавляю степпер: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z9Mr.jpg

после чего хочу настроить его через код, соответственно притягиваю атлет и экшн в UICollectionViewController и пытаюсь присвоить значения, но выходят ошибки. Где я согрешил и как надо сделать чтоб все работало?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvIhb.jpg

П.С. Фото почему то не вставляются поэтому приложил ссылки на имгур, извиняюсь

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вставить stepper.value = 2 внутрь функции IBAction, вот так:

```
@IBAction func itemsPerRow(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    stepper.value = 2
}
```

Cейчас у вас эта строка сама по себе.

Comment: Сделал так, вставилось но значения не присваиваются, что не пишу, как будто не видит

Comment: Чему значения не присваиваются? Что не видит? Хотите увеличить значения степпера, напишите так: stepper.value += 1. Хотите увеличить число ячеек, покажите что у вас в numberOfItemsInSection. Возможно, достаточно написать collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Я хотел чтоб по нажатию на степпер число ячеек в линии увеличивалось. Для этого хотел у степпера стандартное значение установить на 2 (2 ячейки в линии). Сейчас покопался, в метод вьюДоулоад вписал значение степпера и теперь работает